# How can I safely access caught Error properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

### The Situation

I am using TypeScript, and have a try / catch block.  The caught error is typed (`Error`).  I would like to use the error's `message` attribute.

I am using eslint with the [`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-assignment.md) rule enabled.

### The Code

```
try {
  throw new Error('foo');
} catch (err: Error) {
  const { message }: { message: string } = err;
  return {
    message: `Things exploded (${message})`,
  };
}
```

### The Problem

When I run my linter, I receive the following:

```
  4:9  error  Unsafe assignment of an any value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

This is confusing to me, since the error is typed (`Error`).

### The Question

How can I catch an error in TypeScript and access the Error's properties?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

TypeScript 4.0 introduced the ability to declare the type of a `catch` clause variable... [so long as you type it as `unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#unknown-on-catch-clause-bindings):

> TypeScript 4.0 now lets you specify the type of `catch` clause variables as `unknown` instead. `unknown` is safer than `any` because it reminds us that we need to perform some sorts of type-checks before operating on our values.

We don't have the ability to give caught errors arbitrary types; we still need to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) to examine the caught value at runtime:

```js
try {
  throw new Error('foo');
} catch (err: unknown) {
  if (err instanceof Error) {
    return {
      message: `Things exploded (${err.message})`,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to this, it is completely valid (while also completely unreasonable) to throw values of arbitrary types in Javascript, a-la `throw 42`, hence why it's not valid to not mark `err` as `Error`.

Comment: @etheryte while it is possible to throw any type of value, why does typescript does not allow the author to explicitly mark the error as a specific type (assuming that the author knows the code better and would know the type of error being thrown)

Comment: If author knew explicitly error thrown by his code, he wouldn't use types and typescript at all :)

Comment: alternatively `
                    catch (ex) { if (!(ex instanceof Error)) {
                        throw ex;
                    } ...}` which provides the same type guard but has the advantage of not silently swallowing any malformed errors!

Answer (score 25):

Since Typescript 3.7 [you can make an assertion type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

```
export function assertIsError(error: unknown): asserts error is Error {
    // if you have nodejs assert: 
    // assert(error instanceof Error);
    // otherwise
    if (!(error instanceof Error)) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

```
} catch (err) {
  assertIsError(err);
  // err is now typed as Error
  return { message: `Things exploded (${err.message})` };
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer. Unexpected types of cought exceptions should be rethrowed (exception bubbling)

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest using the ternary operator with a type check. The accepted answer allows execution to continue in the case the error is not an Error (e.g. someone has decided to throw 42 or something equally valid yet unreasonable)

```
try {
    throw new Error('foo');
} catch (e) {
    const message = e instanceof Error ? e.message : "Unknown error."
    return {
        message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The catch parameter type can only be any or unknown.
I think in your case it's considered as any.

Is this working in your environment?

```
try {
  throw new Error('foo');
} catch (err: unknown) {
  const { message } = err as Error; // I removed : { message: string } because it should be infered
  return {
    message: `Things exploded (${message})`,
  };
}
```

Comment: This works, but I've found that [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) are risky because they break in hard-to-debug ways. What happens if `err` is not an `Error`? Better to do the runtime check.

Comment: @JasonOwen I agree, I simply haven't thought about it. That's a very good comment as this kind of code is usually placed on entry points of an app.

Answer (score 5):

Visit https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/

" Using unknown in Catch Variables Users running with the --strict flag may see new errors around catch variables being unknown, especially if the existing code assumes only Error values have been caught. This often results in error messages such as:

`Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'unknown'. Property 'stack' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

To get around this, you can specifically add runtime checks to ensure that the thrown type matches your expected type. Otherwise, you can just use a type assertion,

add an explicit : any to your catch variable, or
turn off --useUnknownInCatchVariables."

you can simply add in tsconfig.json:

`"compilerOptions": { "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false }`

or you can use like:

`catch (e: any) {console.log(e.message)}`

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: I made a [tiny library](https://github.com/trevorr/catch-unknown) to make catching `unknown` safely easy:

```
import { asError } from 'catch-unknown';

try {
  throw new Error('foo');
} catch (err) {
  return {
    message: `Things exploded (${asError(err).message})`,
  };
}
```

According to Typescript's `lib.es5.d.ts` file, an `Error` is any object with string properties called `name` and `message` and optionally `stack`.

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}
```

In practice, errors are generally created using the `Error` constructor (which is required for `instanceof Error` to be true):

```
interface ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    readonly prototype: Error;
}

declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

The `catch-unknown` library provides two simple functions:

```
export declare function isError(err: unknown): err is Error;
export declare function asError(err: unknown): Error;
```

`isError` is a typical type guard, which checks for the correct property types, as opposed to using `instanceof` (for maximum compatibility). `asError` is essentially `isError(err) ? err : { name: typeof err, message: String(err) }`, plus handling of a few special cases. 99.99% of the time, values you `catch` are already conform to `Error`, so all that happens is a quick type check.

Comment: That looks like a great library, but the repository is gone from GitHub

Comment: @RobinDaugherty I just fixed the visibility of the repository on GitHub. You should be able to access it now.